# Jest compare json output without writing to a file

Tags: javascript, json, jestjs

just a general question - fairly new to js. I have a script that converts a csv to json. I'd like to test the json output without writing it to a file using Jest. Is that possible with Jest's `expect`?

Answer (score 2):

[As in jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tomatchobjectobject)

> Use .toMatchObject to check that a JavaScript object matches a subset
> of the properties of an object. It will match received objects with
> properties that are not in the expected object.

```
const houseForSale = {
     bath: true,
     bedrooms: 4,
     kitchen: {
       amenities: ['oven', 'stove', 'washer'],
       area: 20,
       wallColor: 'white',
     },
  };

const desiredHouse = {
  bath: true,
  kitchen: {
    amenities: ['oven', 'stove', 'washer'],
    wallColor: expect.stringMatching(/white|yellow/),
  },
 };

expect(houseForSale).toMatchObject(desiredHouse);
```